# Negative values in pie charts

Tags: graph, charts, visualization, pie-chart

My application visualizes data using a variety of chart types. Some data visualized by a pie chart includes negative values. Pie charts aren't designed to display negatives.

**Excel** outputs the absolute value of all values. So, -20 is output in the pie chart as a slice with 20% of the pie's circumference. The only way to tell the number is negative is to reference the legend.

**Highcharts**, which is the charting engine we use, leaves the positive slices intact, but renders the negatives in a very odd and confusing way ([Example on JS Lint](http://jsfiddle.net/E4jg7/)). Props to them for trying to render negatives, but our users are confused.

Others have suggested **filtering out the negatives** altogether, since they don't make sense on a pie chart. This strips data and doesn't wholly represent the data set, so it probably won't work for us.

And, others have suggested **using a more appropriate chart type**, such as a bar chart.

Any other options for solving this? How have you done it?

Comment: I'd say if you (might) have negatives, something else will almost certainly be more suitable If you can't have negatives, something else will almost certainly be more suitable anyway. Pie charts convey information poorly.

Answer (score 5):

Use shades of green for positive values.

Use the absolute value of your negative values to then display different negative values in shades of red.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I thought about the same problem, and made rough sample like this.
Please assume that item B has negative value.

'arc' and 'pie' function of d3.js are very convenient to use.

Working sample is [here](http://hitokun-s.github.io/old/demo/chart/donuts-chart-containing-negative-value.html).

[image: donut chart containing negative value pattern 1]

I also added concentric circles, like this.

[image: donut chart containing negative value pattern 2]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a donut chart around the pie, using one to represent positive values and the other negative values. The key here being the value that represents 100% is the same for both positive and negative. The result is a visual representation of what is positive, negative, and how positive or negative overall the set is.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Answer (score 0):

You could use two donut charts around each other. One represents negative values and the other one positive values (possibly indicate which one is which by using different color gradients, e.g. green/red). The trick is to choose the radius of each donut according to the positive or absolute negative value. If you have an overlap adapt the visualization so that the border between both donuts is exactly at the average of both absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

SO this is what I did in Excel using a Donut Pie Chart:

I have percentage ROI between -8 and positive 8 for 4 items.
I took the sum of these subtracted from one, divided by the number of items, then added it back to itself. This makes everything equal to 1.

Then I made =If commands to sort the numbers to the right and left of the above calculated values for the "Negative side". This provides the ability to make two graphs, one using the left and center positive information, and the other center and left negative information.

So, now each section is given 25% of the cashflow with respect to itself. To the right shows what is using funds, and to the right how much that item is contributing. The graph is set up to show the opposite since its more logical.

Then by removing backgrounds, sizing the charts and rings, and coloring each section still visible or no fill, I was able to make what I wanted to show.

Here's a snip of the excel with the code present. Just replace the =

Hope this helps someone!!

[Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZnJt.png)

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evMIv.png)